# How to set value to text are in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, textarea

I have a text area

> 

I want to set value to this textare from controller. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the value in the Action method to the ViewData:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewData["MyValue"] = "Some text";
  return View();
}
```

Then, use the value to set the text:

```
<%=Html.TextArea("CDescr", ViewData["MyValue"], new { @class = "textarea1" })%>
```

Comment: I tried that also. But it gives error saying that 
"the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.TextAreaExtensions.TextArea(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, object)' has some invalid arguments"

For that I found a solution. I type casted ViewData to string like this..
><%=Html.TextArea("CDescr", (string)ViewData["CName"], new { Class = "textarea1" })%>

It worked... :) Thank you for your reply...